# Gauge/Taiko selector unable to select meta tags

Tags: selector, gauge, getgauge

In Gauge(1.0.6)/Taiko(1.0.0), I'm trying to assert if a certain meta tag exists with the "$" selector using XPath.

```
await $(`XPATH-HERE`).exists()
```

I've tried the following values for XPATH-HERE but all return false:

```
//html/head/meta
/html/head/meta
//head/meta
/head/meta
//meta
/meta
//html/head/meta[@content='ROBOTS']
```

Here's the step sample code:

```
step ("Check meta robots <meta> for this page", async (meta) => {  
    //console.log(await $(`//meta`).get() );
    //console.log( await $('//html/head/meta[@name="ROBOTS"]').exists() );
    assert.ok(await $(`//meta[@content='`+meta+`']`).exists());    
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Taiko tries to filter hidden dom elements by default. Since meta tag is not visible, taiko filters this dom element and you are not able fetch it. 
There is an feature request to enable [Taiko to fetch hidden elements](https://github.com/getgauge/taiko/issues/811), once this is fixed, you should be able to fetch the meta tags.

Comment: **Yep. Got it!

Filed a ticket as well to their GitHub repository.

`
- https://github.com/getgauge/taiko/issues/819
`

**Thank you @neha.